# Editar uma pagina de noticias

Tags: php, mysql

No código baixo, tenho o editor de noticia.

```
<?php

/*
 * faz a conexao ao banco
 * e seleciona a base de dados
 */
include ('../conn/conn.php');
/*
 * monta e executa consulta em SQL
 */
$sql = "SELECT *  FROM noticias   WHERE    n_id = ".(int)$_GET['id'];

$resultado = mysql_query($sql)
or die ("Não foi possível realizar a consulta.");

$linha = mysql_fetch_array($resultado, MYSQL_ASSOC);

?>

<h1>Alterar Noticia</h1>

<form action="alterar_noticia.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>" method="post">

  <label for="titulo">Titulo do Texto: </label>
  <input name="titulo" id="n_titulo" type="text" 
  value="<?php echo $linha['n_titulo'] ?>" /><br />

  <label for="texto">Texto: </label>
  <textarea name="texto" id="n_texto" rows="10" cols="30" /> 
  <?php echo $linha['n_texto'] ?></textarea><br />


  <input type="submit" value="Alterar" />


</form>
```

Mas quando clico no botão *alterar*, redireciona para outra página. 
Onde eu tenho este código:

```
<?php

/*
 * faz a conexao ao banco
 * e seleciona a base de dados
 */
include '../conn/conn.php';
/*
 * monta e executa consulta em SQL
 */
$sql = "UPDATE 
        noticias 
    SET 
        titulo='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['titulo'])."', 
        texto='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['texto'])."', 
    WHERE 
         n_id = ".(int)$_GET['id'];

$resultado = mysql_query($sql)
or die ("Erro ao alterar notícia.");

?>

<h1>Notícia alterada com sucesso!</h1>
```

Neste ultimo código, aparecem erros.

Comment: podemos ajudar. Mas ao olhar para essa pergunta muito dificilmente se percebe alguma coisa... Tenta trabalha-la

Comment: Quais erros aparecem?

Comment: essa resposta que meteram ajudou me mas agr aparece me isto

Comment: Unknown column 'titulo' in 'field list'

que isto quer dizer?

Answer (score 2):

Parece ser erro de sintaxe apenas, tem uma virgula sobrando antes do `where`, remova ela.

```
$sql = "UPDATE noticias SET 
        titulo='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['titulo'])."', 
        texto='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['texto'])."', 
     --------------------------------------------------------^
         WHERE n_id = ".(int)$_GET['id'];
```

Evite utilizar as funções mysql_* elas estão obsoletas, [nesta outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-nao-devemos-usar-funcoes-do-tipo-mysql), tem vários motivos porque **não** utiliza-las.

Não use mensagens de erro genéricas como :

or die ("Erro ao alterar notícia.");

prefira mysql_error() isso dará a mensagem de erro do banco:

```
 or die (mysql_error());
```

Comment: fiz o que disse e agr aparece me isto.
Unknown column 'titulo' in 'field list'
que isto quer dizer?

Comment: Esse erro pode ser causado por não ter uma coluna chamada `titulo` ou alguma aspa perdida. Quando vc executa um `echo $sql` aparece alguma aspa perdida? se puder coloque a saida do echo no comentário.

Comment: mt obrigado pela ajud

Comment: conseguiu resolver? qual era o problema?

Comment: era o nome da tabela nao tava certo

Comment: @Delfino, obrigado pelas correções :D. Para a maioria das linguaguens não precisa adicionar `<!-- language: php -->` o highlight  é definido pela tag da linguaguem,  em alguns poucos caso isso não acontece automaticamente, tbm é util caso vc tenha uma resposta com varias linguagens separadas por bloco.